# Snowflake gives net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Numeric value Error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there an issue with Snowflake's Numeric value? Despite the fact that my data column is String and I am attempting to enter a String value, I regularly receive this problem.

My application is written in Java, and I connect to Snowflake through Jdbc.

```
Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Numeric value 'On Board' is not recognized
```

Nevertheless, when I perform the insert statement manually, it works well.

I double-checked the data and it appears to be correct.

Comment: Hi - it would probably help if you updated your question with the code you are running that generates this error

Comment: Along with a code sample like @NickW mentioned, can you also post the table definition so we can see exactly how the column is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a coalesce() statement involved? I was thrown off by the same "numeric value is not recognized" error and finally realized it was coming from the statement `where coalesce(col_a, col_b, col_c) is not null` -- one of the columns was non-numeric.